# Getting Top 20 mysql Query Error

Tags: mysql

Trying to get: The top-20 PIs who have the largest total amount of awards along with the universities they are affliated with.

Mysql: `SELECT award, pi, org FROM tbl WHERE groupby(award) LIMIT 20`

**Table:**
[image: Table]

It seems to not like my group by. Whats going wrong here?

Comment: You need to aggregate something if you use groupby http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Help with my question please.

Comment: I've not even heard of the `groupby` function; what does it do? (Distinct to the `GROUP BY` clause, that is.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to group something, heres what your trying to do:

```
SELECT distinct award, pi, org FROM tbl LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include columns in a group by query that are not an aggregate column (i.e. the count) or not part of the grouping - this should work:

```
SELECT count(*) as ArwardCount, pi
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY pi
ORDER BY ArwardCount desc
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Comment: gaah I guess I have been stuck with SQL Server too long ;-(

Answer (score 0):

With

```
SELECT award, pi, org FROM tbl WHERE groupby(award) LIMIT 20
```

You would get `SQL Error (1305): FUNCTION xxx.groupby does not exist`

You need the below instead, assuming `pi` alone is unique, and org is in the same table (denormalised)

```
SELECT pi, org, count(award) awardcount
FROM tbl
GROUP BY pi, org
ORDER BY awardcount DESC
LIMIT 20;
```