# Trying to get top 20 mySQL

Tags: mysql

Trying to find: Show the top-20 PIs who have the largest total amount of awards along with the universities they are affliated with.

**Mysql**

```
SELECT max(award), pi, org 
FROM iis 
LIMIT 20;
```

*This only gives me and I want the top 20 records:*
[image: pic2]

**Table**
[image: table]

Anyone??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Top 20 mysql Query Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573431/getting-top-20-mysql-query-error)

Comment: Did you even check the answers against your other question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the awards are not already totaled, then you want to find the sum of the awards for each PI, you need to use SUM, and GROUP BY pi, to sum the awards for each PI

```
SELECT SUM(award) AS totalAwards, pi, org 
FROM iis 
GROUP BY pi, org
ORDER BY SUM(award) DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: mdma - Good calll on the 'sum' part ^^ the above posts missed this.

Comment: Needs an `ORDER BY` clause but you obviously understood the question better than I did :-)

Comment: You're probably best to alias the aggregate column

Comment: @Phil, I was thinking the same thing when I typed in the answer. I've now added an alias.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT award, pi, org 
FROM iis
ORDER BY award DESC
LIMIT 20;
```